# .csv to .arff conversion java

Tags: java, csv, weka, arff

I need to convert .csv files to .arff files.
But my original goal is follows:

- step 1) Take data from MySQL and convert to CSV
- step 2) Convert that CSV file to an ARFF file

I did the first step (created .csv file using java), but when I'm going to convert that to .arff it throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: wrong number of values.
  Read 32, expected 5, read Token[EOL], line 3
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.errms(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getDataSet(Unknown Source)
    at ConvertToArff.main(ConvertToArff.java:21)
```

But when I manually save an MS Excel file and try the .arff conversion code, it is working fine.

Here's my .csv to .arff conversion code

```
String args0="D:\\L4\\final.csv";
String args1="D:\\output.arff";
// load CSV
CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
loader.setSource(new File(args0));
Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
System.out.println(data);

// save ARFF
ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
saver.setInstances(data);
saver.setFile(new File(args1));
saver.writeBatch();
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: First, I would check whether you really created properly the first step. It seems you created a corrupt csv file. Could you share the content of the example file (`final.csv`)?

Comment: (BTW: there are free Java tools that can be used to read from DB and write to arff or even use weka. The first two that come to my mind are: KNIME and RapidMiner.)

Comment: this is the content of sql to csv conversion  http://www.mediafire.com/view/as2orubqa96q363/Main.txt

Comment: Do you understand the code that you linked? For me it seems to write xls(x), not csv.

Comment: yah, that was the problem. thanks Gabor. :)

Comment: You should update the correct answer at the end.